# Behat / Mink Getting value from a CSS Element

Tags: html, css, behat, mink

I have a expandable div on a website. I want to create a test case with Behat/Mink to assert that when the user reaches the page the box is not expanded.

```
<a class="expand" data-reactid=".r[37uxa].[1]" href="#">Click to expand</a>
<div class="expandable" data-reactid=".r[37uxa].[2]" style="height: 0px;">
```

Afterwards when the users clicks the "Click to expand" the value of the style="height" changes:

```
<a class="expand" data-reactid=".r[37uxa].[1]" href="#">Click to expand</a>
<div class="expandable" data-reactid=".r[37uxa].[2]" style="height: 157px;">
```

which means it is now expanded.

I was wondering if there is a way or if i could implement a step definition to check/get the value for the style attribute. Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [`NodeElement::isVisible()`](http://mink.behat.org/api/behat/mink/element/nodeelement.html#isVisible%28%29) to check the visibility of an element.

```php
$session = $this->getSession(); // assume extends RawMinkContext
$page = $session->getPage();

$expandable = $page->find('css', '.expandable');

if (null === $expandable) {
    throw new \LogicException('Could not find the element');
}

if ($expandable->isVisible()) {
    throw new \LogicException('Element is visible...');
}
```

Alternatively inspect the style [attribute](http://mink.behat.org/api/behat/mink/element/nodeelement.html#getAttribute%28%29) yourself:

```
$style = $expandable->getAttribute('style');
```

Answer (score 4):

Thank you both , I was able to work a solution to what I needed with your help. Here is the way I have used:

```
  /**
 * @Then /^The "([^"]*)" element should not be expanded$/
 */

public function theElementShouldNotBeExpanded($element)
{
    $session = $this->getSession(); 
    $page = $session->getPage();

    $expandable = $page->find('css', '.expandable');
    $style = $expandable->getAttribute('style');

    if ($style === "height: 0px;") {
        $message1 = sprintf('Is not expanded having the attribute: '.$style);
        echo $message1; 
    } else {
             $message2 = sprintf('The element is expanded having the attribute: '.$style);
             throw new Exception($message2);

            }
```

}

```
 /**
     * @Then /^The "([^"]*)" element shold be expanded$/
     */
    public function theElementSholdBeExpanded($element)
    {
        $session = $this->getSession(); 
        $page = $session->getPage();
        $expandable = $page->find('css', '.expandable');
        $style = $expandable->getAttribute('style');

        if ($style === "height: 105px;") {
            $message1 = sprintf('Is expanded having the attribute: '.$style);
            echo $message1; 
        } else {
                 $message2 = sprintf('The element is not expanded having the attribute: '.$style);
                 throw new Exception($message2);

                }

    }
```

The step definitions are as follows:

```
Given I am on "/"
        Then  I should see an ".promotion" element
        Then  The ".expandable" element should not be expanded
        And   I follow "Click to expand"
        Then  The ".expandable" element shold be expanded
        And   I follow "Click to hide"
```

And the result:

```
 Given I am on "/"         
 Then I should see an ".promotion" element     
 Then The ".expandable" element should not be expanded
 --Is not expanded having the attribute: height: 0px; 
 And I follow "Click to expand"
 Then The ".expandable" element shold be expanded
  --Is expanded having the attribute: height: 105px;
```

Thank you both , have a nice day!

Answer (score 3):

I suppose you have `$session` from `$session = new \Behat\Mink\Session($driver);`.

You can use `NodeElement::getAttribute('style')`.

```
$page = $session->getPage();
$el = $page->find('css', '.something');
echo $el->getAttribute('style');
```

If it isn't accessible or it doesn't work for you, you can always do

```
echo $session->evaluateScript(
    "(function(){ return document.getElementById('...').style.height; })()"
);
```

Answer (score 0):

When working with JavaScript isVisible not always work as expected.

Example inspecting the style attribute and then the height value:

```
     /**
     * @When /^The expandable div is visible$/
     */
    public function expandableDivIsVisible() {
        $id= 'whatever_expandable_div_id';
        $element = $context->getSession()->getPage()->findById($elementId);

        // This is a good place for using a "spin" functionallity
       if (!$this->elementIsVisibleAndHeightIsHigherThanZero($element)) {
           throw new \Exception(sprintf('Element not visible: %s', $$id));
       }  
    }

   private function elementIsVisibleAndHeightIsHigherThanZero(?NodeElement $element) {

       if (null === $element) {
           return false;
       }

        $dictionary = static:buildDictionaryFromStyleString($element->getAttribute('style'));

        return $element->isVisible() && 
               array_key_exists('height', $dictionary) &&
               (int)$dictionary['height'] > 0
    }

    public static function buildDictionaryFromStyleString($style): array
    {
        $dictionary = [];

        if (empty($style)) {
            return $dictionary;
        }

        foreach (explode(';', rtrim($style, ';, ')) as $css) {
            $parts = explode(':', $css);
            $dictionary[trim($parts[0])] = trim($parts[1]);
        }

        return $dictionary;
    }
```